# How to user docker exec with zsh

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm trying to use zsh instead of bash with the docker exec command, like this:

```
docker exec -it d52b251308b3 zsh
```

Or this:

```
docker exec -it d52b251308b3 /bin/zsh
```

The location is correct but I receive this error:

> rpc error: code = 2 desc = oci runtime error: exec failed:
>   container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "exec:
>   \"zsh\": executable file not found in $PATH"

Comment: You installed zsh in the container? What does `docker exec d52b251308b3 ls /bin/zsh` output?

Comment: sorry my answer was for docker run. First off, are you sure zsh is installed on that image? If it's a publish image can you give us the name.

Comment: can you run `docker exec -it d52b251308b3 whereis zsh`

Comment: Thanks @Novaterata, you guided me to the right answer, I haven't it installed in the container (newbie issues). Please add it as an answer so I upvote you for your great help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like zsh is not installed on that image as /bin/zsh would likely be the path. You can create a new Dockerfile that uses the base image and installs zsh, or you can install it within the container temporarily and launch from bash.

Comment: Thanks for your help, that was it!

Comment: I am trying this command "docker exec -it e1825417c7db /bin/zsh" but is throwing this error "OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "/bin/zsh": stat /bin/zsh: no such file or directory: unknown"

The zsh is already installed in my system.

Comment: @JaypalSodha when you say "installed in my system" do you mean the host OS or the docker container? You can exec with /bin/sh and double check that zsh is in fact installed inside the container